# typescript source map incorrect position in debug mode

Tags: angularjs, typescript, source-maps

i'm using [enter link description here](https://github.com/linemanjs/lineman-angular-template)
I added typescript in my project and build it in following way

```
"lineman-ts": "concurrently 'lineman clean run' 'tsc --target es5 --sourcemap --out app/js/main.js app/js/_all.ts -w'"
```

Everything works well but we have problems with debugging. 
If we put debugger; or breakpoint in dev tools - we see that position of breakpoint is incorrect.

For example i put breakpoint into line 30, open chrome dev tool and try to debug i will see debug point in correct place ( line 30 ) but in fact it is not true. It's very confusing and it's so hard to debug with such problems.

I think it's because of source map.
Maybe somebody was faced with the same problems?

Comment: This can happens because of header injected into output js file.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you please add more details?

Comment: If some tool injects into output js file a header (let's say "/* build date: today or build tool logo or something other */"), this causes lines numbering shift and wrong addressing into source maps. I haven't worked with "lineman-ts" and this is my guess only.